# how to combine two functions and returning an array?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, function, return

hello i would like to shorten my code and would like to combine two functions that exactly do the same.

so i got this:

```
function a($a){
    global $db;
    $query = $db->query("SELECT col_a FROM table WHERE Field= '$a' ");
    $check = $query->fetch_assoc();
    $return_a = $check['col_a'];
    return ($return_a);
}
function b($a){
    global $db;
    $query = $db->query("SELECT col_b FROM table WHERE Field= '$a' ");
    $check = $query->fetch_assoc();
    $return_b = $check['col_b'];
    return ($return_b);
}
```

so i thought i could combine both into one:

```
function ab($a){
global $db;
$query = $db->query("SELECT col_a, col_b FROM table WHERE Field= '$a' ");
$check = $query->fetch_assoc();
$return_array = array( $check['col_a'], $check['col_b'] );
return ($return_array);
}
```

this does not seems to work. i tried reading out the array by using:

```
$db_data = ab($a);

echo $db_data['col_a'];
echo $db_data['col_b'];
```

so if there is someone who could tell what am i doing wrong i really would appreciate.

thanks alot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you do this (same as your code) you can access it like

```
function ab($a){
    global $db;
    $query = $db->query("SELECT col_a, col_b FROM table WHERE Field= '$a' ");
    $check = $query->fetch_assoc();
    $return_array = array( $check['col_a'], $check['col_b'] );
    return ($return_array);
}



$db_data = ab($a);

echo $db_data[0]; // will return 'col_a';
echo $db_data[1]; // will return 'col_b';
```

you should do this

```
function ab($a){
    global $db;
    $query = $db->query("SELECT col_a, col_b FROM table WHERE Field= '$a' ");
    $check = $query->fetch_assoc();
    //$return_array = array( $check['col_a'], $check['col_b'] );
    return ($check);
}
```

and when you need to fetch

```
$db_data = ab($a);

echo $db_data['col_1'];
echo $db_data['col_1'];
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not creating a named array, so your result is indexed with `$db_data[0]` and `$db_data[1]`

Replace:
`$return_array = array( $check['col_a'], $check['col_b'] );`

With:
`$return_array = array( 'col_a' => $check['col_a'], 'col_b' => $check['col_b'] );`

Or even more simpler
just return `$check`;

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$db_data = ab($a);

echo $db_data[0];
echo $db_data[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list($col_a, $col_b) = ab($a);
echo $col_a;
echo $col_b;
```